# Gráfico de pontos Eixo X ggplot2 espaço entre números

Tags: r, ggplot2

Fiz um gráfico de pontos e linhas, como mostrado abaixo. Só que os espaços entre os dados no eixo X ficou de 20 em 20. Eu queria colocar de 10 em 10.

Como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ajustar a escala do seu *plot*.

Considerando que `p` seja seu objeto de *plot* gerado com o `ggplot2`, basta incrementar o ajuste de `breaks` na escala `x`.

```
p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 80, 10))
```

Caso o código aqui exposto não apresente o resultado esperado, por favor, disponibilize o código que foi realizado para gerar seu *plot*.